# jquery ajax returning extra data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Using json_encode($phpArray); to send data back to my javascript. The problem is in javascript there's extra data added to the beginning. Below are simplified examples of my files that still demonstrate the problem.

days.php:

```
<?php
$phpArray = array(
  0 => "Mon",
  1 => "Tue",
  2 => "Wed",
  3 => "Thu",
  4 => "Fri",
  5 => "Sat",
  6 => "Sun",
);
echo json_encode($phpArray);
```

processDays.js:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'days.php',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
)};
```

I'm expecting to get (which I get if I just run the php file on it's own):
["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]

But I'm getting:
22["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]

Where is this 22 coming from??

Comment: *"Where is this 22 coming from?"* Code (or raw text outside of any `<?php ... ?>` section) in your PHP file prior to the code you've shown. Neither `echo` nor `json_encode` is broken (search for "broken" on [this page](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips) for an explanation of that). Voting to close as typo / non-repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should also add datatype for ajax call, if want to get response in json
add datatype as json, as below,

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'days.php',
 dataType: "json", 
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
)};
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio yes, it could be a comment, but i thought to give a full update to code,

Comment: @GRaichand Ignore what I said - looks like it solved OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using json you should declare dataType:"JSON" in ajax